# Query remote machine if specific program installed using wmic and powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

i working on script to check if specifc program are installed on some remote machines using the wmic query and powershell

```
$Machines = Get-Content .\machines.txt 

foreach( $Machine in $Machines) 
{
    Write-Host " Processing Machine $Machine "
    if(Test-Connection $Machine -Count 2 -Quiet)
    {
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Machine -Class Win32_Product  | 
    Select-Object __SERVER, Name, Vendor, Version, InstallDate | 
    sort-object Name | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*Kasper*" -or $_.name -like "*Ivanti*" -or $_.name -like "*Traps*" -or $_.name -like "*microsoft*"} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Export-Csv -Path .\result.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
     }
    else
    {
       Write-Warning "Unable to connect to $Machine" 
       [pscustomobject]@{
            __SERVER = $Machine
            Name = 'not found'
        }       | Export-Csv -Path .\result.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
     } 
}
```

i expect to see the result of my Machine list in one exported CSV file collect the result from machines if it online wirte programs detalis  if it not write "machine not reachable" like below

```
__SERVER    Name    Vendor  Version InstallDate
it01    Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.30729.6161  Microsoft Corporation   9.0.30729.6161  20190626
it01    Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161  Microsoft Corporation   9.0.30729.6161  20190626
it-machine2 Can't reached           
it-machine3 Can't reached           
IT-Machine7 Kasper Endpoint protection  Kasper LAB  10.3.200.2  20190526
```

Comment: [1] you are not using `wmicexe` [*grin*] [2] do a search on `Win32_Product is evil` [3] if you are going to put the found/not-found systems in the same CSV, you SHOULD use the same object structure for reachable and non-reachable systems. if you do not do so, you will have an invalid CSV file. [4] **_what is your question?_** the sample output you posted seems to agree with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ICMP rule is off in windows firewall, server still will be reachable, so the best way to decide that server is not reachable is to let cmdlet Get-WMIobject to fail.
The best way to do parallel actions on powershell is using powershell Jobs.
Hope this helps.

```
$Machines = Get-Content .\machines.txt 
$scriptBlock={
    try
    {
        $result = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $args[0] -Class Win32_Product -ErrorAction Stop  | 
        Select-Object __SERVER, Name, Vendor, Version, InstallDate | 
        sort-object Name | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*Kasper*" -or $_.name -like "*Ivanti*" -or $_.name -like "*Traps*" -or $_.name -like "*microsoft*"} -ErrorAction Stop 
        return @{"Success"=$true; "result"=$result; "server_name"=$args[0]}
    }
    catch
    {
        return @{"Success"=$false; "server_name"=$args[0]}
    }
}

get-job | Remove-Job

foreach($Machine in $Machines) 
{
    Start-Job -Name "Query programs" -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $Machine
}

$processing=$true;
while($processing)
{
    start-sleep 2
    $jobsLeft = Get-Job | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Query programs" -and $_.State -eq "Running"} | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
    Write-Host "$jobsLeft servers still processing"
    if(0 -eq $jobsLeft)
    {
        $processing=$false;
    }
}

[array]$results=@();
foreach($job in Get-Job | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Query programs" -and $_.State -eq "Completed"})
{
    $jobResult = $job | Receive-Job;
    if($true -eq $jobResult.Success)
    {
        foreach($item in $jobResult.result)
        {
            $obj = New-Object PsObject;
            $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ServerName -NotePropertyValue $jobResult.server_name
            $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue $item.Name
            $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Vendor -NotePropertyValue $item.Vendor
            $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Version -NotePropertyValue $item.Version
            $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName InstallDate -NotePropertyValue $item.InstallDate
            $results += $obj
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $obj = New-Object PsObject;
        $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ServerName -NotePropertyValue $jobResult.server_name
        $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue "Can't reach"
        $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Vendor -NotePropertyValue $null
        $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Version -NotePropertyValue $null
        $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName InstallDate -NotePropertyValue $null
        $results += $obj
    }
} 

$results | Export-Csv -Path .\result.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas that was really helpful ... appreciate your efforts